# Why can't I debug my ASP project through a remote desktop connection?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I just asked this question in Stack Overflow but I figured this stack exchange forum is a better fit.

It's been about a month of trying to figure out this problem and we've still not found a solution. We have about seven virtual machines on a server running Windows XP Professional w/ SP 3 all with Visual Studio Interdev and IIS 5.1 installed. Running the programs all work fine, but we just can't debug through remote desktop.

When we are logged into the server console (through VM Sphere) and log into one of the virtual machines through there, we are able to debug properly. We figured the issue lies with some kind of permissions for Remote Desktop Users. We've tried nearly every article on the internet (exaggerating of course) and are about to give up hope.

One more thing, when we are logged into the virtual machine through the server console and then remote in, the user that was logged into the console is kicked off but debugging works! Does remoting in trick the computer into giving us the correct permissions? I'm really not sure how it works.

I know that this technology predates human history, but we are in the process of migrating from ASP Classic to ASP.NET

```
Specs:
  - Windows XP Professional W/ SP3
  - IIS 5.1
  - Visual Studio 6 Interdev
```

---

EDIT: By "debug" I mean running the project with breakpoints.  Interdev doesn't stop at breakpoints.

Comment: Please remove your question on StackOverflow. Cross-posting is not allowed.

Comment: When you say "debug" do you mean just running the program from VS with it in debug mode, or something more complex? What exactly happens when you try to run the debug?

Comment: Here's the process: First, I log into the vm through remote desktop, then I open Visual Interdev. I then put a breakpoint on a line of ASP and run the project. Interdev asks for a password for the debugger and when I input it, the breakpoints still don't fire.